# moved drupal site accepts no links, path, login etc. always shows frontpage

Tags: drupal, authentication

I recently moved some sites resp. I backuped them and did a fresh (ubuntu)server setup. 
Then copied the source back and cat the sql dump again into mysql DB. Apache2 config also fine again.

But now i want to login on the site, but it's not accepted somehow. There is no message, warning and so on. 
All URLs i enter make it show the frontpage.

nothing special in apach2.log
DB seems okay. I also tried purging all cache_ tables.

what else could i check?

Comment: Check that the .htaccess file in the root of your site is still in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouch... mod_rewrite wasnt yet enabled. Thought it is by default on today's apache2.

```
a2enmod rewrite  
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

thx for reading.